# What is the entry point of swift code execution?

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, ios8

There is no `main()` method in swift. The program must start the execution from somewhere. So what is the entry point of swift code execution and how is it decided?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The entry point in a plain Swift module is the file in the module called `main.swift`. `main.swift` is the only file which is allowed to have expressions and statements at the top level (all other Swift files in the module can only contain declarations).

Cocoa Touch uses the [`@UIApplicationMain` attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID348) on an implementation of [`UIApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html) instead of a `main.swift` file to mark the entry point. Cocoa used to use a minimal `main.swift` file which simply called `NSApplicationMain`, but [as of Xcode 6.1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_32) uses the [`@NSApplicationMain` attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID348) on an implementation of [`NSApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html).

Comment: I created a new xcode project and I'm not able to find `main.swift` file anywhere. What is the location of this file?

Comment: In Cocoa and Cocoa Touch applications `main.swift` is in the **Supporting Files** group, and is simply configured to call `NSApplicationMain`.

Comment: No its not there in Supporting files group. Its not anywhere in the project.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about Cocoa Touch but correct about Cocoa. See my updated answer

Comment: Of course, even in Cocoa Touch you can create and use `main.swift`.

Answer (score 48):

In the `AppDelegate.swift` file you can see `@UIApplicationMain`.

The AppDelegate is the initial entry file.

Basically: `main.m` and `AppDelegate.m` are kinda merged in `Swift` to just `AppDelegate.swift`

Comment: @nathan He tagged **iOS8**, that goes for `Cocoa-Touch`, my answer is right.

Comment: Nice, I was wondering how could I change main.m to swift and I didn't find a single thing.

Answer (score 35):

You may want to read [Files and Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7)

> The exception is a special file named “main.swift”, which behaves much
>   like a playground file, but is built with your app’s source code. The
>   “main.swift” file can contain top-level code, and the order-dependent
>   rules apply as well. In effect, the first line of code to run in
>   “main.swift” is implicitly defined as the main entrypoint for the
>   program. This allows the minimal Swift program to be a single line —
>   as long as that line is in “main.swift”.
>
> In Xcode, Mac templates default to including a “main.swift” file, but
>   for iOS apps the default for new iOS project templates is to add
>   @UIApplicationMain to a regular Swift file. This causes the compiler
>   to synthesize a main entry point for your iOS app, and eliminates the
>   need for a “main.swift” file.
>
> Alternatively, you can link in an implementation of main written in
>   Objective-C, common when incrementally migrating projects from
>   Objective-C to Swift.

Comment: I found this to be a way better and higher level explanation of how the entry point is set up in iOS.

Comment: Nice answer, and good link. I then found a good place to put code that needs to run "early". Rather than use one of the app delegate methods, I simply override init on the app delegate, and do it there. I used it e.g. to set up the default logging level.

Answer (score 17):

In Swift 5.3 there is a new `@main` attribute which lets you control where your entry point is in your project rather than just `main.swift`. There can only be one main entry and you can't have a `main.swift` file and a an attribute `@main`. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0281-main-attribute.md for more details.

```
@main
struct App {
    static func main() {
        print("Starting.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift apps there are attributes:

- `@UIApplicationMain` (Cocoa Touch)
- `@NSApplicationMain` (Cocoa)

that tell the swift compiler where is the entry point of the application.

What swift compiler does under the hood is that it creates a `main` function, which basically looks the same as in Objective-C apps and treats this method as the app's entry point (a first method that is called when the application process is started).

If you want to read more about what swift compiler does with `Main` attributes, how the OS knows where is the entry point of the application, I encourage you to read this article: [Understanding iOS app entry point](https://olszanowski.blog/posts/understanding-ios-app-entrypoint/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The entry point in a plain Swift module is the file in the module called.