# Static Block in Swift

Tags: static, swift

In Java, I use static block to execute some code when the class is called like in this example"

```
Class Name
 {
     static
     {
         for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
         {

         }
     } 
 }
```

How do I translate that code in Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["initialize" class method for classes in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137212/initialize-class-method-for-classes-in-swift)

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this,.

```
class SomeViewController : UIViewController {
    public static let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return df
    }()
}
```

Comment: What does the leading `()` denote?

Comment: Answering my own comment - it causes the closure to execute. From a Java perspective you could say it’s short hand for calling run() apply() execute() etc…

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this same question for the last couple days. The solution that I found (although somewhat inelegant) is [the use of `main.swift`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105690/what-is-the-entry-point-of-swift-code-execution).

This isn't really the same thing as a static block on a class in Java, but it may help with your particular issue.

Comment: Wow, I just realized how old this question is! Well, maybe this will be helpful to someone else...