# Building swift application from command line tool: No Info.plist file in application bundle

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to create a Swift application programmatically from the "Command Line Tool" template, and I can't solve the error `No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting`.

Here are the steps I followed :

### Base code

Create an "AppDelegate.swift" class, and delete the "main.swift" file.

Fill "AppDelegate.swift" with the following code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

}
```

### Create and register an "Info.plist" property list

Create a new group named "Supporting Files", and add a new "Property List" named "Info.plist".

In "Info.plist", add a row with the key "Principal class", of type "String", and write "NSApplication" in the Value column.

Register this property list in your project: In "Build Settings", in the "Packaging" part, edit the "Info.plist file" row and write `appName/Info.plist` (appName must be changed according to your Project name).

Is there another thing to do to register this Info.plist file ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your exact goal is unclear — Cocoa [application bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010543-CH8-SW2) (which are actually folders containing the executable and supporting files)  and "command-line"/non-GUI programs are different things. The [`@NSApplicationMain`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) attribute is intended for use only with full Cocoa applications.

Typically if you want to add an application to your project, you'd click the + button to add a new **Cocoa Application target** — but then Xcode will automatically create an Info.plist for you.

For a command-line program, however (as mentioned on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) and discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105690/what-is-the-entry-point-of-swift-code-execution)), you can simply put your code in a file called `main.swift`;

> Code written at global scope is used as the entry point for the program, so you don’t need a `main` function.