# Swift Entry Point

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am very new to Swift, Just one line:

> Code written at global scope is used as the entry point for the program, so you don’t need a main() function. You also don’t need to write semicolons at the end of every statement.

at Official [Swift Tour Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html).

I have gone through [What is the entry point of swift code execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105690/what-is-the-entry-point-of-swift-code-execution)

I really don't understand how main.m is merged with AppDelegate.swift, Can somebody explain it in a simple way. Thanks!

Comment: There is a [@UIApplicationMain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105690/what-is-the-entry-point-of-swift-code-execution) in the AppDeligate which is the entry point.

Comment: ok got it under UIApplicationMain, it is defined:

 public func UIApplicationMain(_ argc: Int32, _ argv: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>!, _ principalClassName: String?, _ delegateClassName: String?) -> Int32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no change in main.m. In swift, if you still want to do any task before AppDelegate excution\call you can create file again.

Please refer below link

https://richardallen.me/2015/05/16/main-swift.html

Hope it will helpful.

**Edit:**
as per my understanding
In swift, main.m is literally not required so, Apple merge it in AppDelegate.

Comment: ok got it under UIApplicationMain, it is defined:

public func UIApplicationMain(_ argc: Int32, _ argv: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>!, _ principalClassName: String?, _ delegateClassName: String?) -> Int32